# the name of state when data reading from hard drive

Tags: cpu-architecture

In computer organization and architecture, what is the name of the state when data must be read from hard drive? I have tried to search it on StackOverflow and textbooks but could not find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In common usage people often say a process is in the *disk wait* or more generally the *i/o wait* state.  In Linux the `systat` command uses the `iowait` label.